# Lirc + irexec config: Repeating keys doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, macbook

I have an Apple remote under Ubuntu, and have installed lirc, and all is kinda working.

irw output is like follows:

```
0000000087ee8104 00 PLAY Apple_A1156
0000000087ee8104 01 PLAY Apple_A1156
0000000087ee8104 02 PLAY Apple_A1156
0000000087ee810d 00 VOLDOWN Apple_A1156
0000000087ee8104 00 PLAY Apple_A1156
0000000087ee810d 00 VOLDOWN Apple_A1156
0000000087ee8104 00 PLAY Apple_A1156
0000000087ee810d 00 VOLDOWN Apple_A1156
0000000087ee8104 00 PLAY Apple_A1156
0000000087ee8104 01 PLAY Apple_A1156
```

As you see, there is a little counter of how many key presses of one unique key I have done. It resets if I don't press anything for a second or two, but otherwise it keeps counting, even if I don't hold the key down.

Now, the problem with this is that irexec doesn't recognize the repeats as key presses and ignores them. This means that I can only press one button once per second, which is enormously annoying.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the repeat option in .lircrc [as seen here](http://www.lirc.org/html/configure.html)

Comment: OK, that worked, but adding it once for every button!? Is there really no better way? OK, fine I only have six buttons, but still. :)